# Tab Bar on top of App in iOS instead of bottom, and customized?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, customization

Is there a way to customize the tab bar to be a custom design instead of how the iOS default design is, and have it at the top of the app instead of the bottom?

Basically I have a custom design for tabs in the app we want to implement and it is on the top, looking similar to below:

[image]

Can I use the Tab Bar controller to achieve this, or do I just have to design it all in a normal view controller and just code everything myself to achieve it?

Comment: I very much doubt it, without diving down into Apple's private APIs, which will likely get your app rejected at the review stage. Is there any particular reason you want the tab at the top, when it is the accepted norm to have it at the bottom on iOS? I hate to be pedantic, but they do have design guidelines for a reason ;) Other than that, though... yeah custom navigation! Good luck!

Comment: Its just the design our artist came up with, having tabbed navigation on the top, is it really so taboo just because iOS has a tabbed bar navigation only on the bottom? Like Facebook has tabs on the top instead of the bottom, I'm sure many other apps make use of one on the top too. The design just looks and works better with it on the top rather than bottom

Comment: I'm not saying don't... but just be wary. Facebook only has buttons which present model controllers, rather than a tabbed navigation. I can't think of any app which does have a tab bar which works similarly to UITabBarController at the top. I'd also be cautious of having important UI elements at the top of the screen due to the new larger phones. Have you also thought about future-planning? If you wanted to put one of the tabs within a UINavigationController your going to have an incredibly tricky time overriding that behaviour too :/ Just seems more trouble than it's worth to me!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it custom. If you're doing this with storyboards I suggest looking for a tutorial on how to implement a vertical tab bar controller (like the one in the Twitter iPad app). There are a few examples out there.

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom container vc for the nav, and separate VC for each content area.

See <del>[this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)</del> for more information (**Edit** - link is dead, [read it](https://web.archive.org/web/20150322105342/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) on Wayback machine).

The main thing you have to do is implement some version of this method provided in the docs as an example

```
- (void) cycleFromViewController: (UIViewController*) oldC

            toViewController: (UIViewController*) newC
```